# Different solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved the following differential equation $(x+y) dx+(y-x) dy=0$,  I have used the substitution $y=xt$ to solve it.  Finally,  I got $$C=2\log x+ \frac12\log(x^2+y^2)-\tan^{-1}\big(\frac yx\big)$$ But the final answer in the book is $$y=\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)+\tan^{-1}\big(\frac xy\big)$$  Why is it different?

Comment: Probably you miscalculate something,  like $\log x - \log x$ is written as $\log x + \log x$ which will give you $2 \log x$ instead of zero.  Yours is $not$ a solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, you should have obtained
$$C=-\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}+1\right)+\log (x)$$ Using $\log(x)=\frac 12 \log(x^2)$ and combining the logarithms, this should give
$$C=-\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(y^2+x^2\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The ODE is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x+y}{x-y} $$
You got :
$$2\log x+ \frac12\log(x^2+y^2)-\tan^{-1}\big(\frac yx\big)=C$$
We check it by differentiation :
$$\frac{2}{x}dx+\frac{x\:dx+y\:dy}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{-y\:dx+x\:dy}{x^2+y^2}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2+xy+2y^2}{x(x-y)}$$ 
This isn't equal to $ \frac{x+y}{x-y}$ . Thus your result is not solution of the ODE.

Since the details of your calculus are not shown one cannot say were is the mistake.

NOTE :

The same method of checking applied to $$\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)+\tan^{-1}\big(\frac xy\big)=C$$
leads to $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x+y}{x-y} $ which proves that this is the correct solution.

NOTE :

$\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)+\tan^{-1}\big(\frac xy\big)=C\quad$ is equivalent to 
$$\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)-\tan^{-1}\big(\frac yx\big)=c$$
with $c=\frac{\pi}{2}-C$ . So both are equivalent expressions of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is my step by step...

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {x+y}{x-y}\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {1+\frac{y}{x}}{1-\frac{y}{x}}$

Which is homogeneous.

$\frac{y}{x} = u\\
y = xu\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = u + x\frac{du}{dx}$

$u + x\frac{du}{dx} = \frac {1+u}{1-u}\\
x\frac{du}{dx} = \frac {1+u}{1-u}-u\\
x\frac{du}{dx} = \frac {1+u^2}{1-u}$

Which is separable.

$\int \frac{1-u}{1+u^2}\ du = \int \frac{1}{x} \ dx\\
\int \frac{1}{1+u^2} - \frac{u}{1+u^2}\ du = \int \frac{1}{x} \ dx\\
\arctan u - \frac 12 \ln {1+u^2} = \ln x + C\\
\arctan \frac{y}{x} - \frac 12 \ln (1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}) = \ln x  +C\\
\arctan \frac{y}{x} - \frac 12 \ln (\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2}) = \ln x  +C\\
\arctan \frac{y}{x} - \frac 12 \ln (x^2 + y^2) + \ln x = \ln x + C\\
\arctan \frac{y}{x} - \frac 12 \ln (x^2 + y^2) = C$

Of course

$\arctan \frac{y}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2} -\arctan \frac{x}{y}$

And we can flip the ssign on everything, getting to the book answer.

It looks like you have the sign flipped at some point on 
$\frac 12 \ln(1 + \frac{y^2}{x^2})$ at some point.
So, when it becomes $\frac 12 \ln(x^2 + y^2)-\ln x$ it has added with the $\ln x$ on the other side of the equation rather than canceling out.